# Seaborn - Matplotlib moving ytick offset

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

Hello I'm learning seaborn, pandas and matplotlib and trying to visualize some data.

Im trying to move the 0 value in 0 axis to x axis. [This is how it looks currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYbWe.png) and I want to move it [down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q250h.png).

Comment: Hey there, I would like you to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and go through [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and make the necessary changes. Its always a good practice to show your research so far and work if necessary as opposed to asking the community to write the code based on your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
sns.regplot(x,y)
plt.ylim(0)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28116534)

Comment: @con Why not? This is an honest attempt to answer. If you think this answer is not good enough, please down-vote. But there is no reason to vote for deletion. Please review more carefully

Comment: @Tomerikoo "Try" is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I've edited my answer

Comment: @con not necessarily. You can't judge an answer by a single word. Please have a look at [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue). Again, this might be a code-only answer or even an altogether wrong answer. This code is still an attempt to answer the question and therefore an answer. As I said, if you think this is not a ***good*** answer, you can down-vote, but ***it is*** an answer...

Comment: @DivyanshChaudhary Worked perfectly thanks !